# How to query the highest altitude within an area of interest in a DTED?

Tags: python, gis, gdal, gdal-python-bindings

I have a rectangular area of interest, and each vertex of this rectangle is defined by a pair of coordinates (latitude, longitude).

Parsing a DTED, how could I find the highest altitude within this rectangular region? I'm using the [dted library](https://github.com/bbonenfant/dted) for python, but I'm open to solutions using [GDAL](https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/) as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the rectangle align with the grid (eg not rotated)? You can convert the corners and read that part of the file, but for a rotated rectangle you somehow also need to rasterize the area of interest somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If the AOI layer aligns with your DTED grid, try:

1. clip the DTED grid in your AOI.
2. convert the clipped grid to points
3. query the max value in altitude column.